# Initializing a const variable by reading its value from file (C++)

Tags: c++, file, constants

I am writing a code where two varibales are constants but they need to be read from a .txt file.

I have written the function

```
void ReadValues(const char filename[],double& sig,double& tau)
{
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open(filename);
  if(!infile.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "File is not open. Exiting." << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  while(!infile.eof())
    infile >> sig >> tau;

  infile.close();
}
```

Obviously I cannot add the const specifier in the prototype. What I do is the following:

```
double s,t;
ReadValues("myfile.txt",s,t);
const double S = s;
const double T = t;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding since C++17, nothing before.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `ReadValues` a little to return the 2 `double`s as a `pair`.

```
auto ReadValues(const char filename[]) -> std::pair<double, double>
{
  double sig, tau;  // local variable instead of reference parameters
  // read from file into sig and tau
  return {sig, tau};
}
```

and now you can make your variables `const` like this.

```
auto const [S, T] = ReadValues("myfile.txt");
```